# Sending a NEC like signal via a GPIO

Tags: led, connection, pwm, signal

I'm trying to control an existing LED strip controller with a Raspberry Pi. The controller has an IR receiver to receive commands. I removed the IR receiver of the controller and added a connection to one of the GPIOs of the Raspberry Pi.

Someone already made the effort to reverse engineer the commands to control the LED Strip (http://blog.allgaiershops.com/2012/05/10/reversing-an-rgb-led-remote/). The data is encoded via NEC. A signal starts with a 9ms low and a 4.5ms high, followed by 0xFF00, and the command and its inverted value (e.g. for red 0x1AE5). A logical one is encoded as an 0.56ms low, followed by an 0.169ms high. A logical zero is encoded as an 0.56ms low, followed by an 0.56ms high.

How do I send such a signal with a Raspberry Pi? Is this done via PWM?

Comment: Simple stuff with precise timing is so much easier to do on an Arduino than a Pi.

Comment: So much so that I'd use an ATtiny -- or, if you're more comfortable with that, an Arduino nano -- that receives data from the Pi through the serial port, and sends out the control signal. That separates the timing sensitive stuff into a dedicated component, which should also make debugging easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a decent programmer you can use pigpio waves to generate the signal.

This is a Python example which uses the kind of techniques you will need to use.

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_irrp_py